# How to create an app that globally handles a Win+<some key> combination?

Tags: c#, c++, keyboard, hook

I want to have an app that handles a key combination (Win key + some other key) globally regardless of what other app is running in windows. (Except possibly inside Win 8 metro mode). How can I do this?

Comment: You've tagged C# and C++. Which one are you using?

Comment: I'm OK with either .NET or C++ if some API is not available directly from .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an API, [RegisterHotKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309(v=vs.85).aspx) that does exactly this. There is even a modifier for the Win key:

> MOD_WIN
>
> 0x0008
>
> Either WINDOWS key was held down. These keys are labeled with the Windows logo. Keyboard shortcuts that involve the WINDOWS key are reserved for use by the operating system.

Note that there is no guarantee that your key combination will be available and not reserved by Windows (now or in the future)

Comment: Thanks! What happens if it *is* reserved? Can't I override?

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk You can use combinations not already in use... For example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767458/how-do-you-register-a-custom-winv-hotkey-on-windows-8 the questioner tried to register Win-V on Windows 8 and failed, because there it's already used for the clipboard.

Comment: Interesting, but RegisterHotKey does not work for me. It consistently returns `false` regardless of keys I provide.

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk Just tested on my Win8 64bits... http://ideone.com/hYc9RY And it works (at least for CTRL+WIN+F1)

Comment: Thanks, I got it working in the end. Turns out you need to feed it something that has a window handle, and I wasn't planning on having anything like that.

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk As in the example I posted, you don't need a windows handle. You can even handle everything through a thread handler.

Comment: Does this work for metro apps also? 
I mean when user is inside of the metro app